# Unable to locate module although it's getting listed by pip

Tags: python, docker

while printing the site packages, it's there. but when importing it, I get an error, module not found.

FYI: it runs inside a container

```
FROM python:3.8.11-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y automake make git zsh util-linux && \
    rm -f /tmp/*

RUN pip install --upgrade pip pipenv

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /code/
WORKDIR /code/

# add requirements
COPY requirements.txt requirements-dev.txt /code/

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
# add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./.docker/entrypoint.sh /code/

EXPOSE 8000

# run server
CMD ["sh", "/code/entrypoint.sh"]
```

src

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages') if isfile(join('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', f))]
print(onlyfiles)
from injectorfount import InjectorFount
```

```
Attaching to meerkat_meerkat_1
meerkat_1  | [2021-07-20 18:26:50 +0000] [9] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
meerkat_1  | [2021-07-20 18:26:50 +0000] [9] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (9)
meerkat_1  | [2021-07-20 18:26:50 +0000] [9] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
meerkat_1  | [2021-07-20 18:26:50 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
meerkat_1  | /code/src
meerkat_1  | /usr/local/bin
meerkat_1  | /usr/local/lib/python38.zip
meerkat_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.8
meerkat_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
meerkat_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
meerkat_1  | ['README.txt', 'zope.interface-5.4.0-py3.8-nspkg.pth', 'clonevirtualenv.py', 'easy-install.pth', '_cffi_backend.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', 'injectorfount.egg-link', 'zope.event-4.5.0-py3.6-nspkg.pth', 'serviceregistry.egg-link', 'cython.py', 'filelock.py', 'six.py', 'platformdirs.py', 'distutils-precedence.pth']
meerkat_1  | [2021-07-20 18:26:50 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
meerkat_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
meerkat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
meerkat_1  |     worker.init_process()
meerkat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 146, in init_process
meerkat_1  |     super().init_process()
meerkat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
meerkat_1  |     self.load_wsgi()
meerkat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
meerkat_1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
meerkat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
meerkat_1  |     self.callable = self.load()
meerkat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
meerkat_1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
meerkat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
meerkat_1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
meerkat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
meerkat_1  |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
meerkat_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
meerkat_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
meerkat_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
meerkat_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
meerkat_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
meerkat_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
meerkat_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
meerkat_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
meerkat_1  |   File "/code/src/meerkat/configurations/app/main.py", line 9, in <module>
meerkat_1  |     from injectorfount import InjectorFount
meerkat_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'injectorfount'
meerkat_1  | [2021-07-20 18:26:50 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
meerkat_1  | [2021-07-20 18:26:50 +0000] [9] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
meerkat_1  | [2021-07-20 18:26:50 +0000] [9] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

entrypoint

```
@cd src; python3 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 meerkat.configurations.app.main:app -w 1 -k gevent --reload && echo "success!" || { echo "Crashed!"; exit 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

turned out to be that initially packages are installed where the docker volume getting mounted because they are installed from a VCS,

So the solution is to install the packages after the volume mount not before, AKA not in Dockerfile but in the entrypoint.sh